# how to Copy files inside Azure Data lake store using C#

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to copy/move the files from one folder to another folder within azure data lake. Business requires to create dynamic folders and move/copy the files. How to do that using c#?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to Move/Rename files from Azure Data Lake Store folder.

If you want to rename the file, keep the dest_path as same.

If you want to move the files across folders then provide the destination folder path starting with "/"

```
DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient();

public static void Move(string src_path, string dest_path)
                {
                    _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Rename(_adlsAccountName, src_path, dest_path);
                }
```

> **Calling Method for Renaming the file:**
>
> Move(_sourcePath + filename, _destinationPath +
>   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)+".tsv");
>
> **Calling Method for Moving the file:**
>
> Move(_sourcePath + filename, _destinationPath + filename);

Comment: can you please share the code snippet to move files between the data lake store folders. Since I am not getting the move method.