# Return Error code when file is not found in API call C#

Tags: c#, api, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create API calls to read file from **azure data lake store**. However I am **unable to show proper response and error for specific file found and not found respectively**.

I am able to connect with azure data lake and fetch data as well, used `try-catch` properly. Please help me with proper response body and response codes for `c#` APIs.

```
try
        {
            string aa = GetItemInfo("/myfolder/subfolder/testfile.txt");
            return new string[]
            {
            "Hello",
            aa,
            "World"

        };
            }
catch {
            return new string[]
         {
            "Hello",
            "World"

     };
```

My code is working. As I am new with API calls on C# I am unable to figure out to correct method to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons which will cause an exception. For example, network issue or token is expired. To show proper response and error for specific file found and not found, I suggest you check the path is exist or not before read the item information.

```
public static  bool ItemExist(string path)
{
    return _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.PathExists(accountName, path);
}
```

Code which use ItemExist method to check whether the path is exist.

```
string path = "/myfolder/subfolder/testfile.txt";
if (ItemExist(path))
{
    string aa = GetItemInfo(path);
    return new string[]
    {
        "Hello",
        aa,
        "World"
    };
}
else
{
    var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    responseMessage.Content = new StringContent("The file path which you requested is not found");
    throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
}
```

For other unexpected exceptions, I suggest you use [Global Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) in your ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: Thankyou for the bool function, that worked. Also, please help me out how to copy a file from one folder to another using c# on azure

Comment: Please reference this thread  [how to Copy files inside Azure Data lake store using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973705/how-to-copy-files-inside-azure-data-lake-store-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Thankyou for the link, but that one is for moving data. I just want to copy same data from one folder to another.

Comment: I am sorry to tell that copy method is not implemented in C# SDK currently. I suggest you do the copy action by downloading file and uploading the file.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank-you for the help over this. I will do download and upload then.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the following

var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage>(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

> throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);

you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api) and also [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling)